# Fix table width in Vue, and add tooltip if the text overruns

Tags: vue.js, tooltip

Essentially, I want a table which you don't have to scroll across to page to view all its content.

Instead, if the text is too long to fit in a table, I want there to be a tooltip which compensates for this.

I don't want to set the width of the table statically, as I want it to stretch across the div in the same manner on different screens.

```
 <tbody>
        <tr v-for="row in rows">
            <td tabindex="0">{{ row.longname }}
                <span
                    v-tooltip.right="{ html: 'overrunning', class:'tooltip' }"
                ></span>
                 <div id="overrunning">
                    <p>The over running text</p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td tabindex="0">{{ row.name }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```